# GitLab: How can I require a manual step for only production?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to have a pipeline that requires manual approval for production but auto deploys everywhere else. So the pipeline stages for non-prod would just be `build` -> `deploy` and for production it would be `build` -> `review` -> `deploy`, so basically the review stage is only for production.

In the UI, I imagine the pipeline would look something like:

```
build        review        deploy
-----        -------       -------

prod ------> review ------> deploy-prod
dev  ---------------------> deploy-dev
```

Is this possible?

Comment: How do you differentiate your pipeline? are they different branches? Or do you use tags? Depending on how you do this, the answer varies a bit, but generally you will probably use the `only` keyword. see the documentation https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic

Comment: We will be using either tags or a `$CI_ENV_VAR` of some sort denoting it's for production

Answer (score 1):

Conditional stages can be defined with the `only` keyword.
See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic

For Variables use something like:

```
review:
  only:
    variables:
      - $CI_ENV_VAR =~ /some value/
```

or for tags:

```
review:
   only:
      - tags
```